# Does this function have a unique fixed point?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems, nonlinear-system

Consider the following equations in fixed-point form:
$$\mathbf{x}=F(\mathbf{x})=[f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}),\cdots,f_n(\mathbf{x})]^T$$
where the function $f_i$ is defined as
$$f_i(\mathbf{x})=\tau_i\prod^n_{k=1}(1-a_{ik}x_k)$$
in which $\tau_i\in(0,1)$, $x_i\in[0,\tau_i]$, and $a_{ik}$ is either $0$ or $1$ for all $i,k\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

Now, my question is that how to prove $F$ has a unique fixed point $\mathbf{x}^\ast$ such that for each $x^\ast_i\in[0,\tau_i]$.